# Bootstrap navbar with collapsible search form

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to fix a bug on the [Linux Kamarada](http://kamarada.github.io/) website regarding the search form. It is inspired on the one present on the [Android](https://www.android.com/)'s website, which is an expanding search bar:

[image]

It works very well on [Mozilla Firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/firefox/), but not at all on [Google Chrome](https://www.google.com/chrome/).

Once, browsing through the web, I came across [HPE](https://www.hpe.com/)'s website and I found their search form awesome:

[image]

It works well on all browsers, so I thought it could be a solution to my problem.

I've tried to imitate it using [Bootstrap's dropdown](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns) (see [this example](https://www.bootply.com/RkDZcAAnSA#)) and here is what I've got so far (I've used [Bootstrap's Fixed navbar example](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/) as a starting point):

[image]

([source code available at Bootply](https://www.bootply.com/3x6gwBO3cz))

According to tests made with [Web Developer](https://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/)'s View Responsive Layouts, it is working as expected on small, medium and large devices (768px wide and up), but not on extra small devices (e.g. mobile portrait, 320x480):

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix that?

Also, for the hamburguer menu to work the way I wanted, I ended up duplicating HTML code. Does anyone know how could I avoid that?

Last but not least, I'm not sure that code is accessible. I would appreciate very much advice about that.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was almost giving up and thinking about using a simple `navbar-form` with a search input (like [this](https://www.bootply.com/7vF6CMXcwO) I found [googling](https://www.google.com/search?q=bootstrap+navbar+with+search+form)), that was when I found this, exactly what I was looking for: [Bootsnipp Navbar with Search](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/a6aV0) (that snippet is very close to the search actually used by the Bootsnipp website itself).

I liked it and adapted it to the [Linux Kamarada](http://kamarada.github.io/) website. The result can already be seen in production:

[image]

I tested it and it works on [Mozilla Firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/firefox/), [Google Chrome](https://www.google.com/chrome/) and [Microsoft Edge](https://www.microsoft.com/windows/microsoft-edge).

Just in case anyone needs, I tried to catch the very basics of the idea and applied the navbar with collapsible search form to the [Bootstrap's Sticky footer with navbar example](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/examples/sticky-footer-navbar/). The result can be seen here: https://www.bootply.com/cf8Go56f4p

[image]

Also, just in case anyone is looking for a navbar with search and hits this page, I found this snippet interesting and recommend it: [Simple Navbar Search](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/simple-navbar-search)

Comment: That was made using Bootstrap v3. I haven't found anything like that using Bootstrap v4, so if you visit Linux Kamarada website today you are going to see a common search form...